# Angular 2 [hidden] does not seem to be working?

Tags: angular

My component is defined this way:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'sidebar',
    templateUrl: 'js/app/views/sidebar.html',
})
export class SidebarComponent {
    public sections: boolean[] = [
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false
    ];
}
```

The `sidebar.html` template:

```
<h3 class="proofTitle">...</h3>
<p [hidden]="sections[0]">
    ...
</p>
<p [hidden]="sections[1]">
    ...
</p>
...
<p [hidden]="sections[7]">
    ...
</p>
```

Seems pretty straight forward, but for some reason, it's showing all of the sections... what am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked if the hidden attribute is added to the elements in the DOM? (in devtools)

Comment: Yes it is.... and with that I spotted my error too... the `boolean array` needs to have its values reversed... duh

Answer (score 69):

Check that you don't have any *display* css rule on your `<p>` tags that would override the `hidden` behavior like:

```
p {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Because the `hidden` html attribute behaves like `display: none`

Comment: I don't get your point @MarkRajcok, angular2 adds or remove the `hidden` html attribute depending of the expression following with this syntax. And my answer talks about an error non related to angular. This is about the behavior of it which could be overrided by a css rule. https://davidwalsh.name/html5-hidden

Comment: Sorry, I read your answer too quickly... I thought I read "be sure to have" not "be sure to don't have"... my mistake. I removed my comment.

Comment: There is no need to specify the "!important" since the [hidden] rule is only "display:none". So if you, by any chance, define a stronger rule for display in your css it will not work.

Comment: !important should never be a solution

Answer (score 20):

Just add this code:

```
p[hidden] { display: none; }
```

to your `styles.css` file.

Comment: Great answer! This overrides the display styling I have on my elements for when I don't want it shown.

Answer (score 15):

if `display: none` property is override use `*ngIf="false"`

Comment: Hidden it's different than *ngIf. [hidden] just hide an element, instead, ngIf recreate an element every time the expression gets set to true. So it's more expensive and should not be used instead. You should now where to use one or the other.

Comment: to avoid css unwanted behavior, ngIf is recommended instead of hidden here to: http://angularjs.blogspot.fr/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html (see first section)

Answer (score 6):

In fact, to hide elements leveraging the HTML5 `hidden` attribute, the value `true` must be returned by your expression. In this case, the attribute will be present in your in-memory DOM. When the value is `false`, the attribute isn't present and the element is visible.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative, use this:

```
[style.display]="sections[i] ? 'none' : 'block'"
```

Answer (score 3):

if you go to dom you can see that hidden make this style

```
p[attributes Style]
{
   display: none;
}
```

and this affects all p element, you can see how to work here:

http://www.talkingdotnet.com/dont-use-hidden-attribute-angularjs-2/

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened because I omitted `name` attribute, needed to make `alert condition` work:

```html
<div [hidden]="submitted">  <!-- wasn't working -->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="model.name"
LOOK-HERE:  name="name"
            #name="ngModel">

        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
                class="alert alert-danger">
            Name is required
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```