# Angular ngClass or hidden with async pipe for loading indicator?

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular 6 app, I have implemented a loading bar on all HTTP requests, using the HTTP interceptor. Essentially returning an observable in a **loaderService**. This works as intended and I am able to add a loading bar on every request with the code below.

```
    <mat-progress-bar
      *ngIf="loaderService.isLoading | async"
      color="accent"
      mode="indeterminate">
    </mat-progress-bar>
```

This requires the async pipe to work, however I would much rather prefer to simply hide/show the bar rather then to use ngIf to remove/add from the dom which shows content being moved when its added or removed.

I would be inclined to use `ngClass` or `[hidden]` however I do not know how or if the async pipe can be used with this. In my attempts, it has not worked. Are there any alternatives to achieve what I require?

Comment: What were your attempts? Could you please post them?

Comment: `[hidden]="loaderService.isLoading | async"` did not work?

Comment: it did not work, however even [hidden]="true" as a test, did not hide it. it is always visible.

Comment: You probably have a `css` somewhere that has `display:inline` or `display:block` with `!important` marker on it. Possibilities like that make use of `[hidden]` unreliable. So, think what you are asking for :)

Comment: If you are still inclined to use hidden, refer to this post there are several helpful suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650410/angular-2-hidden-does-not-seem-to-be-working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 \[hidden\] does not seem to be working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650410/angular-2-hidden-does-not-seem-to-be-working)

Comment: thanks Aragorn. I will look through. Adding a hidden class normally, works but adding through             [ngClass]="{
          'hidden': loaderService.isLoading | async
        }"    , adds the class but has no effect.

Comment: thanks SkyHigh, unfortunately it doesn't update the class when a request is fired. I'm not convinced the async pipe can be used on here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still struggling with this, add a wrapper on top to then apply the hidden attribute.

```
<div [hidden]="!(loaderService.isLoading | async)">
   <mat-progress-bar color="accent" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
</div>
```

The reason why the hidden attribute doesn't work directly on the mat-progress-bar is because it has a `display: block` applied at the class level which is more relevant than the attribute.

Another option by css is to add this:

```
mat-progress-bar[hidden] { visibility: hidden; }
```

(This is better since no jumpy-effect is seen)