# Cannot hide span with [hidden]

Tags: angular

I have an array of objects with the following fields {w: string, s: number, e: number: k: number}. k can be either 0 or 1.
I want to place each word in a span if the `k === 0`;
I am trying to do this with hidden attribute but doesn't work, it doesn't hide the spans if the k field is equal to 1.

Here is my code

```
<span class="word" *ngFor="let word of words"
      [attr.data-m]="word .s" [attr.data-d]="word.e"
      [hidden]="word.k === 1">
      {{word.w}}
</span>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 \[hidden\] does not seem to be working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34650410/angular-2-hidden-does-not-seem-to-be-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this way ?

```html
<span [class.hidden]="k === 1">{{ ... }}</span>
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `ngIf`

```
<span *ngIf="k==1"></span>
```

Comment: ngfor and ng if doesnt work together at same element in angular2+. For this wau you can use ng-template inside

Comment: if you want you can use two span nested

Comment: span in span is not good element architecture design